# How to can i control on the Bitmap size that will be draw on ImageButton?

Tags: android

On my code i need to create some table that each column contain Bitmap and text - and i create this table dynamically. 
So i doing this by using this code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i++) 
    {               

      ObjectITem item = collection.get(i);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);            
        textView.setText(item.getText());            

        linearLayout.addView(textView);            

        linearLayout.addView( (new ImageButton(this)).setImageBitmap(item.getBitmap());
        layout.addView(linearLayout, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        

    }
```

this code is working good  -  but because the originaly images are not in same size - i see that the images that appear on the ImageButton are look not good.

1. How can i make all the images on the ImageButton to look the same ?
2. Is there some better way to make the layout that i did here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) to scale all the images to a desired size. Like this...

```
Bitmap buttonBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(item.getBitmap(), buttonW, buttonH, true);
linearLayout.addView((new ImageButton(this)).setImageBitmap(buttonBmp);
```

2) You might want to consider using a [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) and a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html). This is more complicated, but may be more efficient if your collection is large and needs to scroll over many pages.